# Best way to synchronize sql table to another db sql table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm building a monitoring tool which analyzes information in some sql tables and creates some charts and alerts based on some configurable criterias. However the underlying application is now getting some errors. I think it's because my queries are rather intensive on the tables which causes them to be locked for some amount of time and my idea of a work around is to synchronize the tables to a monitoring database and do my operations there.

Do you have any other ideas? And if I do the sync, whats the best way of syncing tables in SQL server? I prefer if the sync is as close to real-time as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running SQL Server 2008 R2 or above, [Transactional Replication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176(v=sql.105).aspx) is usually a good fit for this type of scenarios and can support near real time synchronization. Here are few links to get familiar with Replication

- [Overview of replication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500346(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Use of replication for data warehousing and reporting applications](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151784(v=sql.105).aspx).

The other solution is to Log ship the transactional database to reporting database.But

1. Log shipping is asynchronous operation, so the state of data in reporting database will be behind that of the data in transactional database.
2. You need to log ship the entire database even if you end up using only couple of tables.
3. The reporting database is not available when it is restoring from the transactional database.

so that would not match to your requirements.

Comment: perfect, than you. Do you have any hands on experience with replication?